# Position text at left and right end of Div

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to web design and I have an issue with a header div at the top of my web page. I want to display the User's Name that's logged in on the left, and the date on the right end. Here is the CSS and HTML Code:

```css
.introHeader {
  background: #494949;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-weight: Bold;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.user {
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.date {
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerIntro">
  <div id='user'>User</div>
  <div id='date'>Date</div>
</div>
```

However, this is what my code yields:
[image]

Any suggestions on how to get the text positioned correctly?

Comment: In CSS you use `#` to select an element by the ID. The `.` selects the class. So `#date` and `#user`

Comment: In the html you used `class="headerIntro"` and in the css `.introHeader` . These names must be the same so in the css it has to be `.headerIntro`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css

```
.headerIntro {
  /* next line because using padding and border */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: #494949;
}
#user {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#date {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
}
```